# android techic about web-services when "no internet connection"

Tags: android, web-services, sqlite, connection

i made an android apps with web-services, right now i am able to do that even though is still simple. My problem is, when there is "no internet connection", i want the app can still be open, with the last data it get from web-services.

> my Question is, how do i do that? is it using sqlite, so after fetching the data from web-services, i have to save it to sqlite? then the data in Listview should be from sqlite not directly from web-services?

Comment: That's one way to do it, and has a lot going for it.  But the answer is going to be caching in some way, wether its in SQLite, the file system, or some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it using sqlite, so after fetching the data from web-services, i have to save it to sqlite?

**YES**

then the data in Listview should be from sqlite not directly from web-services?

**YES**

It's more easier if you can use library. Like retrofit to access webservice. and use ORM to save data to sqlite more easier. But you must 
understand the pattern. And if you undestand it, wuuusssshh more faster while development.

Have Fun!